# Override "type" declaration from external library

Tags: typescript

In an external library, there is type declared in this way:

```
export type Column<D extends object = {}> =
    | SthUnnessary<D>
    | SthUnneededAsWell<D>
```

I would like to override it with:

```
type Column = string | number
```

I read about merging declaration and declaration file, but I cannot find something about how to overrride `type` (not `interface` what I was able to do)

Comment: As far as I know, this isn't possible. But I wonder, why would you want to? Their declarations/API seems to be designed to only accept specific types, why pass any other types?

Comment: @KelvinSchoofs, the problem is this type is wrong in external lib and this external lib use this type inside. I tried to workaround, but there is still the same problem. We cannot suddenly use another lib...

Comment: Ah I see. I'd suggest making an issue on their project or so, getting them to fix it. As for an immediate fix, besides forking the module or starting to modify stuff within your `node_modules`, you can simply use `as any` anywhere where you need to pass a `Column<D>` value. Not ideal, of course.